# Windows 11 update & GVIM menu disappearing

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows

I haven't seen this issue from any searches - am I the only one with this problem?

I just installed the latest Windows 11 update - & suddenly, all gvim menus have "kind of" disappeared...

Both top level menus & right-click context menus - they are still there, but like of size 0 - I get up & down arrows, but no entries (see screenshot) - I can't select anything.

I first had this issue when I installed a "beta" build of windows 11 2 weeks ago - so I rolled that back, all was good again, but today I installed the new official update of windows 11, and the problem came back.

I can roll back again, but maybe there is some simple solution I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: This seems like a bug in Vim; you will probably get better results [reporting this on the issue tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues); unless my search failed me, I don't think someone reported this before.

Comment: Maybe Vim uses a Windows Menu API discontinued in W 11 version 22H2 - but I've used it since Windows XP - up to and INCLUDING Windows 11 - until the update a couple of weeks ago.

I'm having weird selection issues in some other applications as well - SmartGit and NoSQL Booster. Whatever I try to select with the cursor, actually selects a couple of lines above where I click.  Menu, text editing pane, everything - but just for a few programs. Others work just fine.

Or something very specific to my system configuration/setup - I haven't seen similar reports. Very frustrating.

Oh, well...